# Is there an Ioc container that supports assembly versioning by reflection?

Tags: web-services, reflection, asp.net-web-api, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I'm trying to create a web api application that could support 3-4 similar web sites as a backend. Sometimes I'll need to deploy changes and fixes to my backend  that are not as critical to all sites, so I want to expose the API in Urls dependent on my version (.../v1.0.0.3/StuffControler/DoSomething). For that I need the ability to load several versions of my assemblies at once. I can write my own implementation of that using reflection, but I'm using Ioc container that loads my implementation - my question is : could it also pick the assemblies by a given parameter (version number)

Comment: Please, explain a little better what you're trying to achieve. I understand what IoC is, and know what is a container, but I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: rephrased my question. thanks